# Can I use Amazon Route 53 for DNS Round Robin without a custom domain name?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I want to use Route 53 to experiment with DNS Round Robin load balancing of several EC2 instances. Can I do this without having/using a custom domain name?

Comment: If you have an existing domain of any sort, point a subdomain of it at Route53 (via delegation using NS records for the subdomain) for experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize route 53 private DNS, assuming your clients are in your vpc.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/route-53-update-private-dns-more/